# Remote Access to Domain Controller Security Events

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I would like to pull Security events from two Domain Controllers remotely to audit use of an account and to provide guidance for account lockouts.
Locally on the DC my Powershell works fine *provided* Powershell is run with *Elevated privileges*.
Remotely having added the account used to the AD "Builtin" folders security group "Event log readers", i can access events other than Security events remotely. However a line like below does not work for Security Events. Zero events are returned.

`` $events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dc -Credential $cred -scriptblock {Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']=`'$account`']]"} ``

Tips appreciated how i get past the need for elevated privileges remotely ?

Comment: "Zero events are returned." - if it was an access issue you'd receive an error. Sounds more like your filter just isn't matching any events. Try changing `$account` to `$using:account`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, changing $account to $using:account made the difference!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the paramters `ComputerName` and `Credential` with the Cmdlet `Get-WinEvent` and query the events like this:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $dc -Credential $cred -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']=`'$account`']]"
```

or - if you stick to `Invoke-Command` you have to use `$using:account` instead of `$account` within the ScriptBlock (like @Mathias said in the comment) to send that local variable to the remote host

```
$events = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $dc -Credential $cred -scriptblock {Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='TargetUserName']=`'$using:account`']]"}
```

Comment: $using:account worked. Trying Get-WinEvent directly resulted in a CPU loop on the DC for minutes (i aborted so dont know if it would ever reply) when the same query on the DC took seconds.

Comment: However this has shown another issue, the Event->Properties->SyncRoot part of the event is empty, perhaps related to Elevated privs or some deep copy issue. Will address in another post.